# Entity Framework. таблица ссылающаяся на себя

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Коллеги, помогите пожалуйста.

**EF, Code First.**
Есть таблица, в которой я хочу хранить генеалогическую информацию о лошадях (ссылки на мать и отца, если они известны). Насколько я это себе представляю, каждая запись таблицы может содержать от 0 до 2 внешних ключей, ссылающихся на первичный ключ другой записи этой же таблицы.

**1.** Для меня проще использовать `DataAnnotations`, поэтому начал я так

```
public class Horse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Father")]
    public int? FatherId { get; set; }
    public virtual Horse Father { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Mother")]
    public int? MotherId { get; set; }
    public virtual Horse Mother { get; set; }
}
```

Во время создания миграции получаю ошибку. `Horse_Mother_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Horse_Mother_Target' in relationship 'Horse_Mother'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.`. Тут я не понял проблемы, поясните пожалуйста что не так?

**2.** Добавляю к классу св-во Children, описывающее вторую сторону связи.

```
public class Horse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Father")]
    public int? FatherId { get; set; }
    public virtual Horse Father { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Mother")]
    public int? MotherId { get; set; }
    public virtual Horse Mother { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Horse> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Миграция создается без ошибок, но выглядит так:

```
        AddColumn("dbo.Horses", "Horse_Id", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.Horses", "FatherId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Horses", "MotherId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Horses", "Horse_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Horses", "Horse_Id", "dbo.Horses", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Horses", "FatherId", "dbo.Horses", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Horses", "MotherId", "dbo.Horses", "Id");
```

Два требуемых внешних ключа создались, смотрят куда надо, однако что это за столбец `Horse_Id`и почему он автоматически генерируется, непонятно...

**3.** Решил попробовать FluentApi. Убрал DataAnnotations в классе, написал такое:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Horse>()
            .HasOptional(h => h.Father)
            .WithMany(x => x.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FatherId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Horse>()
            .HasOptional(h => h.Mother)
            .WithMany(x => x.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.MotherId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

По смыслу похоже на правду. По итогу получил следующую ошибку: `Sequence contains no matching element`. Тут вообще никаких мыслей нет, что произошло...

**4.** Решил попробовать создать только 1 внешний ключ. Убрал кусок, связанный с MotherId (DataAnnotations выкинул еще до этого), оставил только

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Horse>()
            .HasOptional(h => h.Father)
            .WithMany(x => x.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FatherId)
```

И неожиданно получил миграцию, которую хотел увидеть изначально:

```
CreateIndex("dbo.Horses", "FatherId");
CreateIndex("dbo.Horses", "MotherId");
AddForeignKey("dbo.Horses", "FatherId", "dbo.Horses", "Id");
AddForeignKey("dbo.Horses", "MotherId", "dbo.Horses", "Id");
```

После таких приключений я окончательно запутался. Прошу, поясните по пунктам, где именно я некорректно прописывал требования к EF и как это надо было делать правильно. Как следует конфигурировать связи в общем случае, когда в одной таблице 2 и более внешних ключа, указывающих на одну и ту же таблицу.

Comment: а если попробовать добавить аннотацию `ForeignKey` для навигационных свойств: `Mother` & `Father`?

Comment: @Bald вообще-то, у него та же проблема, что и у вас была :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov я думал об этом, но не был до конца уверен в этом

Comment: @Bald пробовал, ничего не менялось. Выдавало ошибку, аналогичную аннотации `ForeignKey` для ключей

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша проблема - в соответствии между навигационными свойствами. Свойства, ведущие в две стороны, идут парами. Вы разбиение на пары не указывали - отсюда и странности.

Ваша первая попытка сделала два свойства - Father и Mother - встречными друг другу (они стали такими автоматически). Разумеется, это глупо и даже сама EF это поняла, о чем и сказала, пусть и в такой странной манере:

```
Horse  <-> Horse
-----------------
Father <-> Mother
```

Во втором варианте EF не смогла объединить свойства в пары - и они стали независимыми:

```
Horse  <-> Horse
-------------------
Father  -> 
Mother  -> 
       <-  Children
```

В третьем варианте вы попробовали сопоставить свойство Children два раза. EF так не умеет:

```
Horse  <-> Horse
-------------------
Father <-> Children
Mother <-> Children
```

В четвертом варианте вам только кажется что все правильно. На самом деле вы сопоставили Father и Children, а Mother осталась без пары:

```
Horse  <-> Horse
-------------------
Father <-> Children
Mother  ->
```

---

Теперь как делать правильно. Способ первый. Отказываемся от общего свойства Children:

```
class Horse {
  // ...

  public virtual Horse Father { get; set; }
  public virtual Horse Mother { get; set; }
  [InverseProperty("Father")]
  public virtual ICollection<Horse> FatherChildren { get; set; }
  [InverseProperty("Mother")]
  public virtual ICollection<Horse> MotherChildren { get; set; }
}
```

Более красивый способ - использовать отдельный класс-связку:

```
class Horse {
  // ...

  public virtual ICollection<HorseParent> Parents { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<HorseParent> Children { get; set; }
}

class HorseParent {
  public int ParentId { get; set; }

  [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
  public int ChildId { get; set; }

  [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
  public bool IsFather { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("ParentId"), InverseProperty("Children")]
  public virtual Horse Parent { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("ChildId"), InverseProperty("Parents")]
  public virtual Horse Child { get; set; }
}
```

Здесь я использовал составной первичный ключ для того, чтобы ограничить число родителей.

PS если у вас возникает проблема с каскадным удалением - уберите конвенцию  OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention из ModelBuilder или переходите c DataAnnotations на FluentApi.

---

Но это еще не идеал. Дело в том, что в текущем виде лошадь может быть одновременно отцом для одного ребенка и матерью - для другого. Этого можно избежать путем включения пола в первичный ключ:

```
class Horse
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public bool IsMale { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HorseParent> Parents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HorseParent> Children { get; set; }
}

class HorseParent
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public bool IsChildMale { get; set; } // Не нужно семантически, но нужно для внешнего ключа

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public bool IsFather { get; set; }

    public virtual Horse Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual Horse Child { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder b)
{
    b.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    b.Entity<Horse>().HasMany(h => h.Parents).WithRequired(h => h.Child)
        .HasForeignKey(p => new { p.ChildId, p.IsChildMale });
    b.Entity<Horse>().HasMany(h => h.Children).WithRequired(h => h.Parent)
        .HasForeignKey(p => new { p.ParentId, p.IsFather });

    b.Entity<HorseParent>();
}
```

Теперь сама СУБД будет отслеживать, что пол родителя соответствует его роли, а родители каждой лошади - разнополые.

Comment: Для пола лошади [нет специального термина](http://www.equine-world.co.uk/about_horses/equine_gender.asp), зависит от возраста и обстоятельств. (Как и в русском: жеребец, конь, мерин.)

Comment: @VladD вот как раз в русском языке есть слово, которое подходит для любых животных (самец).

Comment: можно попробовать использовать **gender**

Comment: @Bald gender не может быть булевым, а при заведении перечислимого типа возвращается та же проблема :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, самец безотносительно к лошадям — это вроде бы male.

Comment: @PavelMayorov во первых, огромное спасибо за подробный ответ. Есть несколько вопросов. Поясните для начала, откуда берется св-во с именем Horse в ваших схемах к моим ошибкам (`Horse  <-> Horse`). Такого св-ва не объявлено вроде. Для объявленых в классе навигационных св-в типа `Horse` прописаны внешние ключи (атрибутом `ForeignKey`).

Comment: @nikita это заголовок (имя класса) :)

Comment: @VladD да, спасибо, исправил

Comment: @PavelMayorov тестирую ваши варианты. заметил интересную особенность c самым первым из них (`FatherChildren`, `MotherChildren `). Я делаю к таблице простейший запрос `FirstOrDefault()`, не включая никаких дополнительных `Include(h => h.Father)`. Однако все виртуальные св-ва (`Father`, `Mother`) все равно заполнены корректными данными, как будто `Include()` выполнился. Причем заполнены до самого конца, до прадедов... Посмотрел материализованный запрос, ничего криминально нет, обычный `SELECT` без `JOIN`. Может у Вас сть какие нибудь мысли?

Comment: @nikita ленивая загрузка же