# Иерархический каталог пользователей

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Вот задался вопросом создать интересную структуру. Но что то не получается.

```
 public class GroupModel {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GroupModel> GroupModels { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserModel> UserModels { get; set; }
}
public class UserModel {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GroupModel> GroupModels { get; set; }
}
```

Есть вот 2 таких модели. Смысл такой хочу создать каталог пользователей. Пользователь может входить в одну или несколько групп.  Группы могут быть вложенными. Кол-во пользователей, групп и уровней вложенности не ограничего. Но Проблема у меня такая.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<GroupModel> GroupModels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserModel> UserModels { get; set; }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupModel>( -- Пытаюсь тут создать объект для загрузки данных в бд но не получается:( -- ).HasData();
    }
}
```

Не получается создать объекты для внесения в бд данных по умолчанию во время создания бд. Может я что не так делаю. Ошибку выдает в modelBuilder не получается ввести коллекцию User и Group.

Comment: какая ©"БазаДанных данных" ?

Comment: mssql с использованием Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore.Sqlserver

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values `.HasDefaultValue(3);`

Answer (score 2):

Ну во-первых, у вас Users и Groups связаны как многие-ко-многим, поэтому:

```
public class GroupModel
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<GroupModel> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Кроме того, если временно забыть про пользователей и рассмотреть вопрос только о том, как сделать иерархические группы - то я бы вышел из положения сделав ключ к самой себе:

```
public class GroupModel
{
    ....

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public GroupModel ParentGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Итого, всё вместе:

```
public class GroupModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public GroupModel ParentGroup { get; set; }

    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GroupModel> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Поищите также у пользователя Майоров Павел ответы - он много отвечал на подобные вопросы:

- [Entity Framework. таблица ссылающаяся на себя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/540009/213987)

И на хабре статьи про хранение иерархий в реляционных СУБД:

- [Иерархические структуры данных и Doctrine](https://habr.com/post/46659/)
- [Хранение иерархических структур](https://habr.com/post/263629/) - табличка в чём выигрываем в разных подходах к хранению

Я кстати сейчас без visual studio под рукой, так что пример не потестил - если что не так - напишите, посмотрю потом не напутал ли чего.

И ещё. Просто создайте пустой проект asp.net core (только поставив Individual User Account) и черпайте себе вдохновение в identity, там же ползадачи вашей есть - Users и Roles в отношении многие-ко-многим, две таблицы и третья для связи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам остаётся только решить подзадачу с иерархическими группами.

Comment: Да я такое думал уже. Есть паттерн  Prototype. Так вот он делает ссылку на самого себя. Но там абстрактный класс и он просто делает метод клона самого себя внутри. Но абстрактный класс нельзя создать по этому я тут задумался

Comment: @JMNext По наследованию гуглите TPT-TPH-TPС ([например](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/7.2.php)), но к этой конкретной задаче не особо подходит.

Comment: Вот и я о том:)  по этому сюда за идеями зашел)